# How can i create two Menu with submenus

Tags: php, html

How can i add another menu with submenus
http://prntscr.com/b4a678
I want to be like this 
http://prntscr.com/b4a6o6

Comment: Anyone can help me ?

Comment: What is html of your image?

Comment: Where is menu that shown in image?

Comment: Do a mock up in CSS/HTML

Comment: any another help please

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this, you can also view it here http://codepen.io/aptorres27/pen/grKrNZ

```js
var ddmenuOptions = {
  menuId: "ddmenu",
  linkIdToMenuHtml: null,
  open: "onmouseover",
  delay: 50,
  speed: 400,
  keysNav: true,
  license: "6c0l68"
};

var ddmenu = new Ddmenu(ddmenuOptions);

function Ddmenu(k) {
  "use strict";
  var p = function(a, b) {
      return a.getElementsByTagName(b)
    },
    o = navigator,
    H = function(a, c) {
      if (typeof getComputedStyle != "undefined") var b = getComputedStyle(a, null);
      else if (a.currentStyle) b = a.currentStyle;
      else b = a.style;
      return b[c]
    },
    s = function(a) {
      if (a && a.stopPropagation) a.stopPropagation();
      else if (window.event) window.event.cancelBubble = true
    },
    gb = function(b) {
      var a = b ? b : window.event;
      if (a.preventDefault) a.preventDefault();
      else if (a) a.returnValue = false
    },
    i, b, w, g = document,
    m = "className",
    a = "length",
    B = "addEventListener",
    mb = ["$1$2$3", "$1$2$3", "$1$24", "$1$23", "$1$22"],
    D = "offsetWidth",
    E = "zIndex",
    j = "onclick",
    c = [],
    y = -1,
    l = 0,
    J = function(a) {
      if (l) l[b][w] = a ? "block" : "none"
    },
    e, ob, d, h = function() {
      return d && d[D]
    },
    r = function(a, c, b) {
      if (a[B]) a[B](c, b, false);
      else a.attachEvent && a.attachEvent("on" + c, b)
    },
    G = function(c, d) {
      var a = c.dd;
      if (h() && a)
        if (d) {
          C(c, "over");
          a[b].height = "auto";
          var f = a.offsetHeight + "px";
          a[b].height = "0px";
          setTimeout(function() {
            a[b].transition = "height " + e.f / 2 + "ms";
            a[b].height = f
          }, 0)
        } else {
          c.dd[b].height = "0px";
          setTimeout(function() {
            A(c, "over")
          }, e.f / 2)
        }
      else {
        d ? C(c, "over") : A(c, "over");
        if (a) {
          a[b].transition = "none";
          a[b].height = "auto"
        }
      }
      c[b][E] = d ? 2 : 1
    },
    cb = "ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch,
    T = (o.msPointerEnabled || o.pointerEnabled) && (o.msMaxTouchPoints || o.maxTouchPoints);
  if (T)
    if (o.msPointerEnabled) var O = "MSPointerOver",
      P = "MSPointerOut";
    else {
      O = "pointerover";
      P = "pointerout"
    }
  var n = function(d) {
      for (var c = p(g, "li"), b = 0, e = c[a]; b < e; b++)
        if (f(c[b], "over")) d != c[b] && G(c[b], 0);
      J(d)
    },
    lb = [/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]+$/, /.*([\w\-])\.(\w)(\w)\.[^.]+$/, /^(?:.*\.)?(\w)(\w)\.[^.]+$/, /.*([\w\-])([\w\-])\.com\.[^.]+$/, /^(\w)[^.]*(\w)$/],
    nb = function(a) {
      return a.replace(/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])?[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]*$/, "$1$3$2")
    },
    eb = function() {
      var c = 50,
        b = o.userAgent,
        a;
      if ((a = b.indexOf("MSIE ")) != -1) c = parseInt(b.substring(a + 5, b.indexOf(".", a)));
      return c
    },
    X = function() {
      e = {
        a: k.license,
        b: k.menuId,
        d: k.delay,
        e: k.linkIdToMenuHtml,
        f: k.speed,
        g: k.open.toLowerCase(),
        h: k.keysNav
      }
    },
    t = eb(),
    z = function(e) {
      var b = e.childNodes,
        d = [];
      if (b)
        for (var c = 0, f = b[a]; c < f; c++) b[c].nodeType == 1 && d.push(b[c]);
      return d
    },
    v = "createElement",
    ib = function(g, b) {
      var d = function(b) {
          for (var d = unescape(b.substr(0, b[a] - 1)), f = b.substr(b[a] - 1, 1), e = "", c = 0; c < d[a]; c++) e += String.fromCharCode(d.charCodeAt(c) - f);
          return unescape(e)
        },
        c = Math.random(),
        e = d(nb(document.domain)),
        f = "%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%20%71%51%28%73%2C%6B%29%7B%76%3";
      if (L(b + c)[a] % (e[a] + 1) > 8) try {
        b = (new Function("$", "_", "e", "a", "b", "c", L(f, c[a]))).apply(this, [e, b, c, d, g, v])
      } catch (h) {}
    },
    q = function(a, b) {
      return b ? g[a](b) : g[a]
    },
    L = function(e, b) {
      for (var d = [], c = 0; c < e[a]; c++) d[d[a]] = String.fromCharCode(e.charCodeAt(c) - (b && b > 7 ? b : 3));
      return false
    },
    hb = function(b, d) {
      var c = b[a];
      while (c--)
        if (b[c] === d) return true;
      return false
    },
    f = function(a, c) {
      var b = false;
      if (a[m]) b = hb(a[m].split(" "), c);
      return b
    },
    C = function(a, b) {
      if (!f(a, b))
        if (a[m] == "") a[m] = b;
        else a[m] += " " + b
    },
    A = function(d, f) {
      if (d[m]) {
        for (var e = "", c = d[m].split(" "), b = 0, g = c[a]; b < g; b++)
          if (c[b] !== f) e += c[b] + " ";
        d[m] = e.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
      }
    },
    Y = function(d) {
      if (!h())
        for (var b = 0, e = c[a]; b < e; b++)
          if (d != c[b].a && f(c[b].a, "over")) return 1;
      return 0
    },
    M = function(a) {
      return a.pointerType == a.MSPOINTER_TYPE_MOUSE || a.pointerType == "mouse"
    },
    S = function(b) {
      var a = this;
      a.a = b;
      a.b = null;
      a.k()
    },
    V = function(a) {
      this.a(a);
      this.b(a)
    };
  S.prototype = {
    l: function(b) {
      var a = this;
      clearTimeout(a.b);
      if (b) {
        a.f();
        J(1)
      } else a.b = setTimeout(function() {
        a.f()
      }, Y(a.a) ? 0 : e.d)
    },
    f: function() {
      G(this.a, 1);
      if (!h() && H(this.a, "position") == "static") this.a.dd[b].top = this.a.offsetTop + this.a.offsetHeight + "px";
      else this.a.dd[b].top = ""
    },
    g: function() {
      var a = this;
      clearTimeout(a.b);
      a.b = setTimeout(function() {
        G(a.a, 0)
      }, e.d + 50)
    },
    i: function(g) {
      if (t < 9) {
        var c = z(g),
          d = c[a];
        if (d) {
          c = z(c[0]);
          d = c[a];
          if (d) {
            var e = c[d - 1];
            if (f(e, "column")) e[b].borderRight = "none"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    j: function(b) {
      var a = this;
      s(b);
      if (f(a.a, "over")) {
        a.g();
        !h() && J(0)
      } else a.c(b)
    },
    k: function() {
      var d = this,
        c = this.a,
        g = z(c),
        k = g[a];
      if (t < 7)
        if (f(g[0], "top-heading")) g[0][b].zoom = 1;
      while (k--)
        if (f(g[k], "dropdown")) var i = g[k];
      if (i) {
        f(g[0], "top-heading") && g[0].setAttribute("aria-haspopup", "true");
        d.i(i);
        c.dd = i;
        c.setAttribute("tabindex", 0);
        if (f(c, "full-width")) i[b][E] = 2;
        i[j] = s;
        if (e.g == j) c[j] = function(a) {
          d.j(a)
        };
        else if (T) {
          c[j] = function(a) {
            if (h()) d.j(a);
            else s(a)
          };
          r(c, O, function(a) {
            if (!h())
              if (M(a)) d.l(a);
              else {
                s(a);
                d.c(a)
              }
          });
          r(c, P, function(a) {
            !h() && M(a) && d.g()
          })
        } else {
          c[j] = function(a) {
            d.j(a)
          };
          c.onmouseover = function() {
            !h() && !l && d.l(0)
          };
          c.onmouseout = function() {
            !h() && !l && d.g()
          }
        }
      } else {
        c.onmouseover = function() {
          C(this, "over")
        };
        c.onmouseout = function() {
          A(this, "over")
        }
      }
    },
    c: function() {
      !h() && n(this.a);
      this.l(1)
    }
  };
  V.prototype = {
    a: function(a) {
      ib(a, e.a)
    },
    b: function(j) {
      if (cb && /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(o.userAgent)) {
        l = q(v, "div");
        j.insertBefore(l, j.childNodes[0]);
        var f = l[b];
        f.position = "fixed";
        f.left = f.right = f.bottom = f.top = "0px";
        f[w] = "none";
        f[E] = -1
      }
      if (!I) {
        r(g, "click", function() {
          n(0)
        });
        r(window, "resize", function() {
          var a = h();
          if (y != a)
            if (y == -1) y = a;
            else {
              y = a;
              n(0)
            }
        })
      }
      for (var p = z(j), m = 0, s = p[a]; m < s; m++) p[m].nodeName == "LI" && c.push(new S(p[m]));
      (new Function("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", function(d) {
        for (var c = [], b = 0, e = d[a]; b < e; b++) c[c[a]] = String.fromCharCode(d.charCodeAt(b) - 4);
        return c.join("")
      }("jyrgxmsr$N,|0}-zev$eAjyrgxmsr,f-zev$gAf2glevGshiEx,4-2xsWxvmrk,-?vixyvr$g2wyfwxv,g2pirkxl15-\u0081?vixyvr$|/e,}_6a-/}_4a/e,}_5a-/e,}_4a-\u0081jyrgxmsr$O,-zev$tAQexl_g,+yhukvt+-a,-?mj,tB2:-zev$uAk,g,+jylh{l[l{Uvkl+-0g,+kktlu|'{yphs'}lyzpvu+--0vAm_oa0wAv_oa?mj,tB2=-wAk,+fsh}+-?mj,tB2<-w_oa_g,+puzly{Ilmvyl+-a,u0w-?ipwi$w_g,+puzly{Ilmvyl+-a,u0v-\u0081\u0081?mj,j-j2wx}pi2~Mrhi|Am2~m|/5?zev$qAe2e\u0080\u0080+::+0rAtevwiMrx,q2glevEx,4--\u0080\u0080:0zAk,g,+kvthpu+--?mj,z2pirkxl@8\u0080\u0080z2vitpegi,z2wpmgi,5015-0++-AA+px+-zev$sAq?ipwi$sAN,r/+g+0z2vitpegi,h_r16a0l_r16a-2wtpmx,++--?s2mrhi|Sj,q-AA15**O,-?mj,f-f2srgpmgoAjyrgxmsr,-mj,i,-**q%As-O,-\u0081"))).apply(this, [e, l, L, lb, h, d, q, mb, j, 0, i]);
      !I && e.h && k.license[a] == 6 && r(g, "keydown", ab);
      Z(j)
    }
  };
  var db = function() {
    var c = p(g, "head");
    if (c[a]) {
      var b = q(v, "style");
      c[0].appendChild(b);
      return b.sheet ? b.sheet : b.styleSheet
    } else return 0
  };

  function Z(f) {
    if (typeof f[b].webkitAnimationName != "undefined") var d = "-webkit-";
    else if (typeof f[b].animationName != "undefined") d = "";
    else return;
    var h = "@" + d + "keyframes ddFadeIn {from{opacity:0;} to{opacity:1;}}",
      i = "#" + e.b + " li.over .dropdown {" + d + "animation: ddFadeIn " + e.f + "ms;}";
    if (g.styleSheets && g.styleSheets[a]) {
      var c = db();
      if (c && c.insertRule) {
        c.insertRule(i, 0);
        c.insertRule(h, 0)
      }
    }
  }
  var N;

  function ab(b) {
    var j = b.which || b.keyCode;
    if (!/^(37|38|39|40|27|9)$/.test(j)) return;
    var h = g.activeElement;
    if (h == d && t > 8 && j == 9 && b.shiftKey) {
      x();
      return
    }
    for (var e = 0; e < c[a]; e++)
      if (h == d || h == c[e].a || f(c[e].a, "over") || h[i] == c[e].a) {
        if (j != 9) {
          gb(b);
          s(b)
        }
        break
      }
    clearTimeout(N);
    N = setTimeout(function() {
      jb(b, j)
    }, 10)
  }

  function u(c, b, e) {
    b = b + e;
    if (b < 0) b = c[a] - 1;
    if (b >= c[a]) b = 0;
    if (c[b].a.getAttribute("tabindex") != null) {
      c[b].a.focus();
      F(c[b], c[b].a)
    } else {
      var d = p(c[b].a, "a");
      if (d[a]) {
        d[0].focus();
        F(c[b], c[b].a)
      } else u(c, b, e)
    }
  }

  function bb(b, a) {
    return !a || a.nodeType != 1 ? 0 : a[i] == b ? 1 : a[i] && a[i][i] == b ? 1 : 0
  }

  function F(a) {
    n(0);
    a.l(1)
  }

  function x() {
    f(d, "menu-icon-active") && d[j]()
  }

  function jb(s, b) {
    var e = g.activeElement;
    if (e == d) {
      if (b == 9) !f(d, "menu-icon-active") && d[j]();
      if (b == 27) {
        x();
        d.blur()
      }
      b == 40 && u(c, -1, 1);
      return
    }
    var h = -1;
    if (e)
      for (var m = 0; m < c[a]; m++)
        if (e == c[m].a || f(c[m].a, "over") || e[i] == c[m].a) {
          h = m;
          break
        }
    if (h != -1) {
      var l = c[h].a;
      if (b == 27) {
        n(0);
        l.blur();
        x();
        return
      }
      if (b == 37) u(c, h, -1);
      else if (b == 39) u(c, h, 1);
      else {
        var o = p(l, "a"),
          k = -1;
        if (!o[a]) return;
        for (var q = 0; q < o[a]; q++)
          if (e == o[q]) {
            k = q;
            break
          }
        if (b == 38) k--;
        else if (b == 40 && k < o[a] - 1) k++;
        else if (b == 9) {
          if (e && !f(l, "over")) F(c[h], l);
          else if (k == -1 && e != l)
            if (bb(l[i], e)) {
              if (t < 9) var r = 1;
              else r = s.shiftKey ? -1 : 1;
              u(c, h, r)
            } else {
              n(0);
              x()
            }
          return
        }
        k >= 0 && o[k].focus()
      }
    }
  }
  var W = function(c) {
      var a;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) a = new XMLHttpRequest;
      else a = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      a.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (a.readyState == 4 && a.status == 200) {
          var e = a.responseText,
            f = /^[\s\S]*<body[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/body>[\s\S]*$/i;
          if (f.test(e)) e = e.replace(f, "$1");
          var d = q(v, "div");
          d[b].padding = d[b].margin = "0";
          c[i].insertBefore(d, c);
          d.innerHTML = e;
          c[b][w] = "none";
          Q()
        }
      };
      a.open("GET", c.href, true);
      a.send()
    },
    R = function() {
      i = "parentNode", b = "style", w = "display";
      if (e.e) {
        var a = q("getElementById", e.e);
        if (a) W(a);
        else alert('Cannot find the anchor (id="' + e.e + '")')
      } else Q()
    },
    K = 0,
    I = 0,
    Q = function() {
      if (!K) {
        var c = q("getElementById", e.b);
        if (c) {
          for (var i = p(c, "*"), h = 0; h < i[a]; h++)
            if (f(i[h], "menu-icon")) {
              d = i[h];
              break
            }
          c = p(c, "ul");
          if (c[a]) {
            c = c[0];
            if (d) {
              if (t < 9 && d[D]) e.g = j;
              d[j] = function(a) {
                c[b][w] = c[D] == 0 ? "block" : "";
                if (c[D] == 0) {
                  n(0);
                  A(this, "menu-icon-active")
                } else C(this, "menu-icon-active");
                s(a)
              };
              var g = H(c, "z-index") || H(c, E);
              if (g == "auto" || g == "") g = 1e10;
              c.zix = g;
              d.setAttribute("tabindex", 0)
            }
            new V(c);
            K = I = 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    fb = function(c) {
      var a = 0;

      function b() {
        if (a) return;
        a = 1;
        setTimeout(c, 4)
      }
      if (g[B]) g[B]("DOMContentLoaded", b, false);
      else r(window, "load", b)
    };
  if (t < 9) {
    var kb = q(v, "nav"),
      U = p(g, "head");
    if (!U[a]) return;
    U[0].appendChild(kb)
  }
  X();
  fb(R);
  return {
    init: function() {
      K = 0;
      R()
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#ddmenu
{
    display:block;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center; /*Specify the alignment of the whole UL if UL is not width:100%;*/
    letter-spacing:normal;
}

#ddmenu ul
{ 
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center; /* Alignment of each top-level menu items within the UL */
    width:1200px;
    font-size:0;
    background:#F1F1F3;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999999990; 
    border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #dddddd;
}

#ddmenu li
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:14px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1; /*for IE6-7*/
    position:relative;
    color:#666;
    line-height:44px; /*This determines the height of the menu*/
    vertical-align:middle;
    transition:background-color 0.2s;
    outline:none;
 -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

#ddmenu .full-width {
    position:static;
}

#ddmenu .over
{
    color:#FFF;
background-color:#0099FF;
}

#ddmenu .over.no-sub {
    
}

#ddmenu .top-heading
{
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0 22px;
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block; 
    outline:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* links of top-heading */
#ddmenu a, #ddmenu a:link, #ddmenu a:hover
{
    color:inherit;
}
#ddmenu a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#ddmenu a:focus
{
    outline:1px dotted #09F;
}

/* caret(arrow icon) */
#ddmenu .caret
{
    color:inherit;
    left:-18px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;/*for IE6*/
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border-top: 4px solid;/*caret size is 4px now*/
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}  
        
/* sub-menu layout
----------------------------*/

#ddmenu .dropdown
{
    width:auto;    
    left:0px;
    color:#000000;
    padding:0;margin:0;display:none;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;
    top:100%;
    border:1px solid #ddd;border-top:none;
border-radius:0 0 2px 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

#ddmenu .full-width .dropdown {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#ddmenu .offset300 {
    left:-300px;right:auto;
}

#ddmenu .right-aligned {
    left:auto;
    right:0px;
}

#ddmenu .over .dropdown
{
    display:block;
}

#ddmenu .dd-inner {
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:13px;
}

#ddmenu ul ul
{ 
    margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;width:auto;background:none;border:none;display:block;position:static;z-index:0;border-radius:0;
}

#ddmenu ul ul li
{
    font-size:13px;
    padding:6px 0; /*It determines the line height*/
    color:inherit;
    line-height:1;
    margin:0;display:block;position:static;background:none;border:none;transition:none;border-radius:0;
}
  
/* links in sub menu
----------------------------*/

#ddmenu .dropdown a
{
    color:#444;
    line-height:1;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:color 0.4s;
}

#ddmenu .dropdown a:hover, #ddmenu .dropdown a:focus
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#09F;
}

/* blocks within the sub-menu
-----------------------------*/
#ddmenu .column
{
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;/*or middle*/
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;*zoom:1;
    white-space:normal;
    width:auto;min-width:200px;
padding:0 30px;
border-right:1px solid #999;
}

#ddmenu .dd-inner ul:last-child
{
    border-right:none;
}

#ddmenu h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#ddmenu .top-heading {text-transform:uppercase;}

/* useful when http://www.menucool.com/ddmenu/one-menu-for-all-pages */
#ddmenuLink {display:none;}
```

```html
<nav id="ddmenu">
    <div class="menu-icon"></div>
    <ul>
       
            
<div class="dropdown">
            </div>
        </li>
       
        <li>
            <a class="top-heading" href="#">menu1</a>
            <i class="caret"></i>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="dd-inner">
                    <ul class="column">
                        <li><h4><a href="#">submenu 1</a></h4></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="#">submenu 2</a></h4></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="#">submenu 3</a></h4></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="#">submenu 4</a></h4></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
<li>
            <a class="top-heading" href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <i class="caret"></i>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="dd-inner">
                    <ul class="column">
  <li><h4><a href="#">submenu 1</a></h4></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```